# Generate Entity classes from an Oracle database using C#

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I need to generate classes from an Oracle database in Entity Framework 6.

Many tables are without a primary key in the database, and Entity Framework didn't generate classes of tables not containing a primary key.

Comment: Can not be done, because a primary key is necessary to identify the records

Comment: Don't generate the classes - write them yourself. It really isn't that difficult.